# String Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am really stuck on this exception

```
private static void getUserComment(String s) {
    while(s.contains("author'>")){
        System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("author'>"),
                                       s.indexOf("<div id='")));
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("author'>")) +
                           s.substring(s.indexOf("<div id='"+9));

    } 
}
```

Comment: What does your input string look like?

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: The printing and the sub string statements both appear to generate this exception

Comment: The input is an html page which is basically this UR: Lhttp://sabq.org/sabq/user/news.do?section=5&id=20908 I trying to extract useful information such as username and the comment of the commenter, I don't know is it the right way to do it or not?

Comment: Get a proper HTML parser which loads the page into a DOM, then query the DOM (for instance with XPath if that is supported). The [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) opensource project may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a proper parser or at least do some regular expression pattern matching (which is already "bad enough" for HTML or XML).

That said, your "offset" of 9 is likely the indirect cause of the exception:

```
s.indexOf("<div id='"+9)
```

This will make a literal string `<div id='9` which is not found; `indexOf` then returns -1 and this causes the exception in the `substring` method. Maybe you wanted to actually add 9 to the index like this? `s.indexOf("<div id='")+9`

Note that the function is useless anyways, changing `s` will only change the local variable and not the original variable (parameters are by value in Java).

Comment: What I want is to cut the author information and use it and find the next author and cut his information from the String, so after some time I will end up with no author... 

I don't know anything about pattern matching will it be a good way to extract information?

Comment: @Nayef - there are lots of resources on pattern matching.  Even books.  As @Lucero say, it will work (most of the time).  But a proper HTML parser is a better idea.

Comment: As I wrote, use a proper parser. The [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) opensource project may fit your needs for extraction (but there are others around as well).

Comment: To be honest it is the first time to hear about DOM, what shall I do read about DOM or go with The HTML Parser?

Comment: DOM stands for "Document Object Model" and it is not a specific piece of code but the general name for a parsed hierarchical object representation model for a document.